# How to store values to db with type Class<? extends View> using Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, orm, hibernate-mapping

In my bean  i have

```
Class<? extends View> viewClass   = null;
```

and my Hibernate mapping file having

```
     <property name="viewClass" type="java.lang.Class">
            <column name="menu_url_class" />
    </property>
```

then it throwing

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to locate named class name.class
```

help me to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Hibernate offers the ClassType](http://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-hibernate-types/) so you can map a Class object to a VARCHAR (or [VARCHAR2 in Oracle](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch05.html#mapping-types-basictypes)).

1. Make sure **menu_url_class** is a VARCHAR.
2. Change the mapping to:

   ```
   <property name="viewClass" type="class">
       <column name="menu_url_class" />
   </property>
   ```

Comment: I didn't understand your edit, so I reject it. Please add more details as a comment. I think type="class" is the right way to instruct Hibernate.